# Can my neighbours affect my credit report and/or credit score?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-score, credit-report

My wife and I live in a single building (in London, England) which contains three flats/apartments.

We rent our flat privately (private tenants, renting from a private landlord) and the other two flats are rented by council tenants (affordable housing) who are unemployed and on benefits.

Both my wife and I are professionals and have good credit reports/scores.

However, we aren't being accepted for things such as credit cards where we have been predicted a 95.00% chance of being accepted.

In this specific case, when discussing this with the potential lender, we were told that our credit report (not necessarily our credit score(s)) was what prevented them from approving us for said credit card.

Without going into specifics, I want to know if the other people living in the building - and their poor credit histories - could have an effect on our personal credit scores.

To make it clearer, I want to know if the people living in 238A and/or 238B (we live in 238C) could negatively impact our credit profiles because they have poor credit scores (we know this because bailiffs often visit to reclaim unpaid debt).

Is this possible?

The reason I ask is because, despite living in different flats, we all technically live at number 238.

Comment: Are you able to view the negative marks on your credit report and contest any that are erroneous?

Comment: In the US, there's something referred to as "redlining", which is the practice of using a ZIP (postal) code to determine acceptance (and, in some cases, rates) for certain products like credit and insurance.  This is generally not legal, but still occurs.  You may be a victim of a similar thing.  It's also possible that your credit report has been conflated by address (the flat # has been dropped) or that the previous resident of your flat didn't handle credit well and your flat has been flagged, although that usually affects things like utilities (gas, electric, cable/phone).

Comment: @Istanari For insurance, pricing based on ZIP or address is definitely legal if there is a relationship between risk and location. Automobile insurance will be higher in ZIP codes where car thefts are higher and in urban areas where traffic is denser. Homeowners insurance will be higher in areas that are subject to wildfires. Health insurance is affected by the price (and costs) of doctors in your area and also ability to access to certain preferred hospitals.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Well, it's not supposed to.  Sometimes, however, data errors happen and credit bureaus report that debts belong to someone with a similar name or address.  That's why it is useful to periodically examine your credit report and contest any entries that are incorrect.

In the US, if you are turned down for credit, you have the ability to obtain the credit report that was used in making that decision.  I'm not an expert in UK law but I would expect that you have a similar ability to get the credit report that was used free of charge.

Comment: That's correct - we have a free credit report service (www.noddle.co.uk) which is owned by TransUnion - one of the three credit bureaus here in the UK... OP could create an account and see / raise any discrepancies through there.

Comment: Also clearscore.com for Equifax reports and I think moneysavingexpert's "Credit Card" for Experian's data. Don't know about "Hunter".

Comment: In the UK there's a statutory requirement that you can get a copy of your credit record by paying a fee of £2 to the credit bureau.  That is different from a credit report, which is a product the bureaux try and sell you (claiming they have some insight on what loans you might get, which is generally up to the lenders not them) on top of a dump of the data they hold on you.  The free services are often some hook for paid credit reports (inviting you to 'upgrade', free trials that you forget to cancel, etc)